# Django migrations wrongly applying

Tags: django, database, mariadb, migration, django-migrations

### Basic problem

I'm working on a django project where I'm using multiple databases with a custom router.
Therefore, django should know which database to use for which app.

Now I came across some in my opinion weird behaviour and wanted to ask if anyone knew if that is the correct behaviour or not, especially because the [github page](https://github.com/django/django) doesn't seem to have an issues tracker.

To make the point clear, I'm using an extreme example, which I nonetheless tried. For testing purposes, I set the `allow_migrate` function to just return `False`.
I did create a custom router which overrides the `allow_migrate` function and I also registered it under the `DATABASE_ROUTERS` settings. The `allow_migrate` function is also called, as I checked it with some `print` statements.

### How I understand the router usage

The way I understand the documentation for [using multiple databases with a custom router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/), the `allow_migration` method specifies if a migration is to be applied for the current `db`, `app_label` and `model_name`.
If it returns `True`, the migration is applied, if `False`, it is 'silently skipped' and therefore not applied.

### What I expected

As I set the `allow_migrate` function to return `False` all the time, I expected that none of the yet unapplied migrations are applied.

### What actually happens

The migrations are, as the documentation states, indeed 'silently skipped', but the table `django_migrations` is nonetheless being filled with the not yet applied migrations.

### Why that is a problem

Therefore, if I had an actual logic in the `allow_migrate` function, even if the migration is correctly not applied, e.g. because the database is being tested for a specific app that should not be stored in that database, the `django_migrations` table of that database is being filled with *wrong* data.

So, is that the wanted behaviour? Am I just using the function `allow_migrate` wrong and should actually be using something else?

In case it is relevant, I'm using `django version 3.1.2` and my database is a `mariadb` database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of figured out how the described problem is actually wanted.

It seems like for every database that `django` knows of, it is writing the migrations that one created with `makemigrations` into the `django_migrations` table, even if it did not actually apply the migration.
Therefore, it keeps track of which migrations are newly created each time and only considers the migrations that are not stored in the `django_migrations` table.

To make it clear once again: **In every case, if a migration is applied or not, it is written into the `django_migrations` table**. If the migration is actually applied is only decided by the `allow_migrate` function I mentioned. There is no clue, however, if the migration actually got applied or not, except for looking into the tables that were changed in that database.

I suggest, that `django` should either say so in the console or just add a field `applied` into the `django_migrations`. Maybe I'm gonna prepare a pull request for that.